# Match exact number of occurrences of multiple letters

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

For context I am using Mongoose and regex to match a string in a database using `find()`.

Given an example string `{W}{W}{U}{U}{B}{B}{R}{R}{G}{G}` I need to match occurrences of certain letters. I'm trying to make a RegExp that will match only when I have the required number of letters.

`{W}{W}{U}{U}{B}{B}{R}{R}{G}{G}` => wwuubbrrgg, ggrrbbuuww, wuwubrbrgg, etc

`{W}{W}{U}` => wwu, wuw, uww, etc

Solutions I found were not able to account for the order of the string being somewhat random and multiple letters potentially being in the same bracket: `{U/R}`. Because of that I only want to take into account the actual letters and only match when it's found the sufficient number of letters and not encountered any letters that are not present.

Comment: this surpasses the goal of regex and gets into the field of sorting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is really, really bad at counting. wanting a specific number of a specific character in no specific order is not something Regex is very good at. It can be done, but not with any reasonable measure of efficiency. As an example, here is a working Regex for your scenario:

```
^(?=[^wW\n]*[wW][^wW\n]*[wW][^wW\n]*)(?=[^uU\n]*[uU][^uU\n]*[uU][^uU\n]*)(?=[^bB\n]*[bB][^bB\n]*[bB][^bB\n]*)(?=[^rR\n]*[rR][^rR\n]*[rR][^rR\n]*)(?=[^gG\n]*[gG][^gG\n]*[gG][^gG\n]*).{10}$
```

As we can see, it's very, very long for something so simple. That's because this behavior is not really what Regex is designed for, as the desired functionality isn't much of a pattern. I would personally recommend going through and simply counting occurences of each character. But, if you're dead set on regex, here's the breakdown:

```
^(?=[^wW\n]*[wW][^wW\n]*[wW][^wW\n]*)(?=[^uU\n]*[uU][^uU\n]*[uU][^uU\n]*)(?=[^bB\n]*[bB][^bB\n]*[bB][^bB\n]*)(?=[^rR\n]*[rR][^rR\n]*[rR][^rR\n]*)(?=[^gG\n]*[gG][^gG\n]*[gG][^gG\n]*).{10}$

^           //anchor to start of string
(?=         //start lookahead
   [^wW\n]* //any number of characters that aren't a 'w' or new line
   [wW]     //followed by the first instance of a character we're looking for
   [^wW\n]* //any number of characters that aren't a 'w' or new line
   [wW]     //followed by the second instance of a character we're looking for
   [^wW\n]* //any number of characters that aren't a 'w' or new line
)           //end lookahead
...         //repeat this for every character we want to be sure is in the string
.{10}       //now actually match the ten characters, now that we know the number of each is correct
$           //then validate that that takes us to the end of the string
```

*EDIT*: Actually, this regex can be reduced slightly down to:

```
^(?=[^wW\n]*[wW][^wW\n]*[wW])(?=[^uU\n]*[uU][^uU\n]*[uU])(?=[^bB\n]*[bB][^bB\n]*[bB])(?=[^rR\n]*[rR][^rR\n]*[rR])(?=[^gG\n]*[gG][^gG\n]*[gG]).{10}$
```

Essentially, this just gets rid of the final negative capture group in each lookahead. It is not necessary since we are constraining the total capture length to the same as the sum of each character requirement. That condition is enough to know that we satisfy the requirement of not having MORE than 2 of any given character. Still, I'd avoid the regex solution to this problem, as in the time taken to generate and run this regex for a given combination of characters you could already have counted the instances of each character and come upon the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like RegEx isn't a viable option. That solution is more complex than I would have imagined. I'll look for a different way to handle this problem.